# How to display all items from an API in React JS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

Below is my code, in this I want to add code to display all the products with its image from an API, how can I do that? Please help?

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
import Axios from "axios"

function Products() {

const [products, setProducts] = useState({});

const fetchProducts = async () => {
const {data} = await Axios.get('https://api.test.ts/demo/test');  
const products= data
setProducts(products);
};

useEffect(() => {

  fetchProducts()

 }, []);

 return(
     
     <div>
         Want to Display list of products from API
     </div>
 )

}

export default Products;
```

Comment: can you tell me what is problem? Your problem is that you dont know how to get products data and use it in Webhook? Or you dont know how to show data in JSX in React?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried your URL for fetching products but it is showing as not reachable so I have coded this simple app using `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com` API of the list of todos.

Hope this example helps you understand how to fetch and display items from fetched data.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  const fetchProducts = async () => {
    const { data } = await Axios.get(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/"
    );
    const products = data;
    setProducts(products);
    console.log(products);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProducts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {products.map((product) => (
        <p key={product.id}>{product.title}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[CodeScandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-thunder-uwcvb?file=/src/App.js:0-579)

Here is another example, where the returned data is in the form of an object instead of an array in the above Example:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Axios from "axios";

const productsData = {
  note: "",
  notification: "",
  Books: [
    {
      bookID: 65342,
      img: "https://source.unsplash.com/200x300/?book",
      year: 2018,
      bookTitle: "Story Time",
      LibraryInfo: {
        Status: "Out",
        returnDate: "7 Jan"
      }
    },
    {
      bookID: 65332,
      img: "https://source.unsplash.com/200x300/?book",
      year: 2018,
      bookTitle: "Story Time",
      LibraryInfo: {
        Status: "Out",
        returnDate: "7 Jan"
      }
    }
  ]
};
export default function App() {
  const [products, setData] = useState(productsData);
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    setData({});
    Axios.get("https://stylmate1.firebaseio.com/hair.json").then((response) => {
      // console.log(response.data);
      setData(productsData);
    });
  }, [toggle]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* <button onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)}>fetch</button> */}
      {products?.["Books"]?.length &&
        products["Books"].map((product) => (
          <div key={Math.random() * 10000}>
            <img src={product.img} width="200" alt="" />
            <p>{product.bookTitle}</p>
            <p>{product.year}</p>
            <p>
              {"Library Status: " +
                product.LibraryInfo.Status +
                "\n" +
                product.LibraryInfo.returnDate}
            </p>
            <p></p>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-golick-trj1f?file=/src/App.js:0-543)  Example Showing how to Render elements from JSON data returned in the form of the object instead of Array Like the above example

Comment: You forgot to use "key" prop.

Comment: showing :- TypeError: products.map is not a function.                                                                 Need to fetch from an object, so .map  can work here?

Comment: you can convert Object to Array with ```Object.entries()``` and use that array to map through it

Comment: if possible, share the api url so that I can see the data it is returning, then only I can give the exact answer

Comment: or paste the data that is being returned from Axios get request

Comment: by writing the following code I can see the data in the console, How do I write this to display in the UI.                                                                                                                    ``` for(const key of Object.keys(products)) {
    console.log("Key",key);
      }
 for(const value of Object.values(products)) {
        console.log("Values",value);
          }
for(const entry of Object.entries(products)) {
            console.log("Entries", entry);
    }```

Comment: just show me the data that is being returned, based on that I can give you the specific ans, How am I supposed to know what keys are you using, what those keys are storing, which element of what object that is you are trying to display on ui

Comment: added the example showing object data rendering, check out

Comment: Thank You Ketan for you help , this is the data-----                                                                                           
{
  "note": "",
  "notification": "",
  "Books": [
    {
      "bookID": 65342,
      "img": "https://unsplash.com/photos/AqX_786_G0g",
      "year": 2018,
      "bookTitle": "Story Time",
      "LibraryInfo": {
        "Status": Out,
        "returnDate":7 Jan        
      }
    },

Comment: the data that is being fetched is in the same form that I have rendered, so rendering logic will not be much different, just assign the fetched data and from axios request to products state and follow the same rendering logic that is being used in the example.

Comment: As I don't have the API URL so there is only one way I could have shown you the rendering logic is by saving the similar data locally and render it.
Here is a similar app that takes in JSON data in the form of object and renders it,https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/object_flatlist  I have possibly gave you all the variable solution, now its up to you to study them and implement correctly.

Comment: @KetanRamteke - Thank You - Can You Please Help - Your answer is helpful but I don't want to get data locally I want to get more data from an API so how can I do it for const productData.

Answer (score 1):

```
   return (
     <div>
       {products.map((product, index) => (
        <p key={index}>{product.title}</p>
       ))}
     </div>
   );
```

It's recommended to have a product id, instead of using the array index as a key prop.

```
   return (
     <div>
       {products.map(({ id, title }) => (
        <p key={id}>{title}</p>
       ))}
     </div>
   );
```

That 'key' prop helps React detect & change the modified items using their unique 'key' prop.

Comment: showing :- TypeError: products.map is not a function.                                                                Need to fetch from an object, so .map  can work here?

Comment: that is because your 'products' variable is null, you can see that by console.loging the data variable you received after you fetched the api, try to check if you fetched correctly.