# Getting empty sets from REST api, how do i get the bank parameters

Tags: react-native, rest

i want to get the list of banks in Nigeria as well as their codes. it just returns more of an empty set. How do i make it get the respective data from Json like the bank name as well as the code and use it in my code?

My code looks like this

```
  getLocalBanks = async () => {

    var url = 'https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/banks/NG';

    fetch(url + email, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer FLWSECK_TEST-72fe360edef17334f4817a17407011bb-X',
      },
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        setGetBanks(responseJson);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };
```

and calling it , I do it like this

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    getLocalBanks();
    console.log({getBanks})
  });
```

but i am getting a very empty set when i interract with the REST api

Full source code is like this

```
import {
  ImageBackground,
  Modal,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import {Picker} from '@react-native-picker/picker';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import BackgroundOpacity from './BackgroundOpacity';

const LocalPayments = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const[getBanks, setGetBanks] = useState([])
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  getLocalBanks = async () => {

    var url = 'https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/banks/NG';

    fetch(url + email, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer FLWSECK_TEST-72fe360edef17334f4817a17407011bb-X',
      },
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        setGetBanks(responseJson);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };

  useEffect(()=>{
    getLocalBanks();
    console.log({getBanks})
  });

  showBanks = () =>{
    alert({})
  } 

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <BackgroundOpacity
        display={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? false : modalVisible}
      />
      <View style={styles.space} />
      <ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={{
          justifyContent: 'space-between',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        <ImageBackground
          source={{
            uri: 'asset:/logo/bg.JPG',
          }}
          imageStyle={{borderRadius: 6}}
          style={{
            top: -30,
            paddingTop: 95,
            alignSelf: 'center',
            width: 328,
            height: 115,
            borderadius: 9,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignSelf: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.accText}>Wallet Balance</Text>
            <Text style={styles.text}> 250,000 </Text>
          </View>
        </ImageBackground>

        <View
          style={{
            borderRadius: 5,
            borderWidth: 1,
            overflow: 'hidden',
            height: 35,
            padding: 0,
            borderColor: '#00BB23',
          }}>
          {
            <Picker
              style={{
                width: 300,
                height: 55,
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
              }}
              itemStyle={{
                fontSize: 25,
                fontFamily: 'Poppins-Medium',
              }}>
              <Picker.Item label="Select Bank" value="accNum" />
            </Picker>
          }
        </View>
          <View style={styles.space}/>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Destination Account"
          onChangeText={creditAccount => this.setState({creditAccount})}
          style={styles.input}
        />

        <TextInput
          placeholder=" Amount"
          onChangeText={amount => this.setState({amount})}
          style={styles.input}
        />

        <TextInput
          placeholder=" Narration"
          onChangeText={description => this.setState({description})}
          style={styles.input}
        />

        <View
          style={{
            borderRadius: 5,
            borderWidth: 1,
            overflow: 'hidden',
            height: 35,
            padding: 0,
            top: 10,
            borderColor: '#00BB23',
          }}>
          {
            <Picker
              style={{
                width: 300,
                height: 55,
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
              }}
              itemStyle={{
                fontSize: 25,
                fontFamily: 'Poppins-Medium',
              }}>
              <Picker.Item label="Currency" value="accNum" />
              <Picker.Item label="NGN" value="NGN" />
            </Picker>
          }
        </View>

        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            setModalVisible(true);
          }}
          style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.loginbtn}> Transfer </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Modal
          hasBackdrop={true}
          backdropOpacity={0.2}
          backdropColor="black"
          transparent
          visible={modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => setModalVisible(false)}>
          <View style={styles.modal}>
            <Text>Hello From Modal</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <Text>Modal! Modal!</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </Modal>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};

export default LocalPayments;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingTop: 40,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },

  modal: {
    top: '50%',
    height: '50%',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  accText: {
    top: -50,
    paddingTop: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-Medium',
    fontSize: 12,
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    top: -50,
    fontSize: 20,
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-Bold',
  },
  input: {
    top: 10,
    width: 300,
    height: 55,
    margin: 10,
    fontSize: 12,
    borderColor: '#00BB23',
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-Bold',
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 30,
  },

  button: {
    marginTop: 40,
    width: 150,
    height: 50,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#00BB23',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  Regbutton: {
    width: 150,
    height: 52,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#030303',
  },

  loginbtn: {
    color: '#ffff',
    fontSize: 15,
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-Medium',
  },

  AccountBalance: {
    fontSize: 13,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'left',
  },

  loginbtn2: {
    color: '#030303',
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },

  logo: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
  },

  space: {
    top: 10,
    width: 10,
    height: 20,
  },

  space2: {
    width: 10,
    height: 10,
  },

  imageStyle: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 5,
    margin: 2,
    height: 15,
    width: 15,
    resizeMode: 'stretch',
    marginBottom: 8,
    marginTop: 8,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

it is supposed to return something like this

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "message": "Banks fetched successfully",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 132,
      "code": "560",
      "name": "Page MFBank"
    },
    {
      "id": 133,
      "code": "304",
      "name": "Stanbic Mobile Money"
    },
    {
      "id": 134,
      "code": "308",
      "name": "FortisMobile"
    },
    {
      "id": 135,
      "code": "328",
      "name": "TagPay"
    },
    {
      "id": 136,
      "code": "309",
      "name": "FBNMobile"
    },
    {
      "id": 137,
      "code": "011",
      "name": "First Bank of Nigeria"
    },
    {
      "id": 138,
      "code": "326",
      "name": "Sterling Mobile"
    },
    {
      "id": 139,
      "code": "990",
      "name": "Omoluabi Mortgage Bank"
    },
    {
      "id": 140,
      "code": "311",
      "name": "ReadyCash (Parkway)"
    },
    {
      "id": 141,
      "code": "057",
      "name": "Zenith Bank"
    },
    {
      "id": 142,
      "code": "068",
      "name": "Standard Chartered Bank"
    },
    {
      "id": 143,
      "code": "306",
      "name": "eTranzact"
    },
    {
      "id": 144,
      "code": "070",
      "name": "Fidelity Bank"
    },
    {
      "id": 145,
      "code": "023",
      "name": "CitiBank"
    },
    {
      "id": 146,
      "code": "215",
      "name": "Unity Bank"
    },
    {
      "id": 147,
      "code": "323",
      "name": "Access Money"
    },
    {
      "id": 148,
      "code": "302",
      "name": "Eartholeum"
    },
    {
      "id": 149,
      "code": "324",
      "name": "Hedonmark"
    },
    {
      "id": 150,
      "code": "325",
      "name": "MoneyBox"
    },
    {
      "id": 151,
      "code": "301",
      "name": "JAIZ Bank"
    },
    {
      "id": 152,
      "code": "050",
      "name": "Ecobank Plc"
    },
    {
      "id": 153,
      "code": "307",
      "name": "EcoMobile"
    },
    {
      "id": 154,
      "code": "318",
      "name": "Fidelity Mobile"
    },
    {
      "id": 155,
      "code": "319",
      "name": "TeasyMobile"
    },
    {
      "id": 156,
      "code": "999",
      "name": "NIP Virtual Bank"
    },
    {
      "id": 157,
      "code": "320",
      "name": "VTNetworks"
    },
    {
      "id": 158,
      "code": "221",
      "name": "Stanbic IBTC Bank"
    },
    {
      "id": 159,
      "code": "501",
      "name": "Fortis Microfinance Bank"
    },
    {
      "id": 160,
      "code": "329",
      "name": "PayAttitude Online"
    },
    {
      "id": 161,
      "code": "322",
      "name": "ZenithMobile"
    },
    {
      "id": 162,
      "code": "303",
      "name": "ChamsMobile"
    },
    {
      "id": 163,
      "code": "403",
      "name": "SafeTrust Mortgage Bank"
    },
    {
      "id": 164,
      "code": "551",
      "name": "Covenant Microfinance Bank"
    },
    {
      "id": 165,
      "code": "415",
      "name": "Imperial Homes Mortgage Bank"
    },
    {
      "id": 166,
      "code": "552",
      "name": "NPF MicroFinance Bank"
    },
    {
      "id": 167,
      "code": "526",
      "name": "Parralex"
    },
    {
      "id": 168,
      "code": "035",
      "name": "Wema Bank"
    },
    {
      "id": 169,
      "code": "084",
      "name": "Enterprise Bank"
    },
    {
      "id": 170,
      "code": "063",
      "name": "Diamond Bank"
    },
    {
      "id": 171,
      "code": "305",
      "name": "Paycom"
    },
    {
      "id": 172,
      "code": "100",
      "name": "SunTrust Bank"
    },
    {
      "id": 173,
      "code": "317",
      "name": "Cellulant"
    },
    {
      "id": 174,
      "code": "401",
      "name": "ASO Savings and & Loans"
    },
    {
      "id": 175,
      "code": "030",
      "name": "Heritage"
    },
    {
      "id": 176,
      "code": "402",
      "name": "Jubilee Life Mortgage Bank"
    },
    {
      "id": 177,
      "code": "058",
      "name": "GTBank Plc"
    },
    {
      "id": 178,
      "code": "032",
      "name": "Union Bank"
    },
    {
      "id": 179,
      "code": "232",
      "name": "Sterling Bank"
    },
    {
      "id": 180,
      "code": "076",
      "name": "Skye Bank"
    },
    {
      "id": 181,
      "code": "082",
      "name": "Keystone Bank"
    },
    {
      "id": 182,
      "code": "327",
      "name": "Pagatech"
    },
    {
      "id": 183,
      "code": "559",
      "name": "Coronation Merchant Bank"
    },
    {
      "id": 184,
      "code": "601",
      "name": "FSDH"
    },
    {
      "id": 185,
      "code": "313",
      "name": "Mkudi"
    },
    {
      "id": 186,
      "code": "214",
      "name": "First City Monument Bank"
    },
    {
      "id": 187,
      "code": "314",
      "name": "FET"
    },
    {
      "id": 188,
      "code": "523",
      "name": "Trustbond"
    },
    {
      "id": 189,
      "code": "315",
      "name": "GTMobile"
    },
    {
      "id": 190,
      "code": "033",
      "name": "United Bank for Africa"
    },
    {
      "id": 191,
      "code": "044",
      "name": "Access Bank"
    },
    {
      "id": 567,
      "code": "90115",
      "name": "TCF MFB"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Edits**
Please see the Package.json

```
{
  "name": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.11",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.8",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.3.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.3",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^6.0.2",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.5",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-text-avatar": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jetifier": "^2.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Lucas I am able to get the banks when I use POSTMAN, there is something wrong with your UI code, let me drill into this further and get back to you.
Can you share your ```package.json``` file also, it will be much easier for me to reproduce your project.

Comment: @Makarand, in want to show it on the banks on the dropdown, select banks

Comment: @Makarand, pls see Edits.

Comment: I think your state is not getting set i.e ```getBanks``` is remaining empty. Also see once if you are setting correct data into ```getBanks```, it should be ```setGetBanks(responseJson.data)``` I will clarify about this in the answer.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65103923/how-to-map-array-of-array-into-react-native-picker) should solve your issue 
I've deleted my answer because it is no longer relevant.